# Why don't I see all AspNetUsers Table Columns when I try to query it using IdentityDbContext?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on ASP.NET MVC5 Application with EntityFramework 6.2.

**I have Article Table and Users Table. Each article has an author which I want to retrieve from AspNetUsers Table.** I have added new columns to this table by modifying **RegisterViewModel** and adding **UserName, FullName, Description** properties to his domain model.

The problem I cannot see this new properties that I have added, but I can see UserId and UserName from AspNetUsers table using these lines.

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

or

```
User.Identity.GetUserName();
```

then I searched I tried to use **IdentityDbContext** and by doing so, I can retrieve data from all AspNetUsers table columns except (UserName, FullName, Description) as you see in this screenshot:

[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3EPK.png)

and this is my table:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFMGd.png)

**I am trying to get FullName to assign to Article Author like so:**

```
var AspNetUser = new IdentityDbContext();
var UserInfo = AspNetUser.Users.Where(u => u.Id == article.UserId);
article.AuthorName = UserInfo.FullName;
```

**RegisterViewModel Domain Model:**

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Full Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

**Article Domain Model:**

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

**Also I wonder? what does it mean if I don't see the properties I did in this reference as this screenshot shows:**

[IdentityUser Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glqco.png)

Comment: Are you using .Net Core ?

Comment: No I use Asp.net MVC 5. I will edit this post to add this info.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that by using **IdentityDbContext**, I cannot query all **AspNetUsers Table Columns**. Using *IdentityDbContext*, you will be able to get data from the original table columns not the ones you have added. 
Let us say you want to get **Phone Number** from AspNetUsers Table. You can get it using **IdentityDbContext** since this column originally comes with with AspNetUsers Table.

```
  ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext();

  var CurrentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();

  string PhoneNumber = Context.Users
 .Single(u => u.Id == CurrentUser)
 .PhoneNumber;
```

**But how to query AspNetUsers Table and get information from the columns you have added?** here is an example to get **FullName** and **Description** of the current logged on user. 


First add this namespace:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```

then

```
string FullName = HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
                .FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).FullName;

string ProfileDescription = HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
                .FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Description;
```